# Support custom downloadable themes for android application

Tags: android, download, themes, customization

I have been able to create and switch themes within my android application using a combination of the theme editor and getting the theme set in each activity before the setcontent method is called in on create and it works brilliant.

However, many apps like GoSMS for example offer downloadable themes as an app that install onto the device and are selectable from the app itself.

How would I go about implementing this feature? It seems a nice clean way of adding extra customisation to an app without having to keep resubmitting an update. It would also offer the opportunity to monitise the additional themes.

I have searched and searched but nowhere seems to have the answer. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
I know the main app theme can be set in the manifest but guess you cannot affect this one the app is compiled and distributed. 
The only other thing I can think of was to use a content provider and try and save the custom values in the main app database but then how would I translate that information so the app would read it in a timely manner.

But to surmise I need a way of offering downloadable custom android application themes and how that would be Implemented in the main application?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you found out the solution?